# Force SSH to ask my private key passphrase in the shell (not in a window)

Tags: shell, ssh, ssh-agent, window

When I use SSH for the first time after booting, it asks me for my private key unlocking passphrase (which is the behaviour I expect). But it does so in a window, not in the shell (similar to `gksudo` VS `sudo`). This is frustrating (I have to use my mouse to click the window) and secondly sometimes causes a bug (I use Guake terminal, sometimes in fullscreen, in which case I can't focus on the SSH window and I am forced to restart X).

So, my question is: **Is there a way to force SSH to ask for my private key passphrase on the command line, instead of popping a window?**

Comment: env ssh ... would do it, but this loses ssh-agent so it's not quite right. Maybe somebody can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 7):

You probably have one of the `*-askpass` packages installed, and the environment variable `SSH_ASKPASS` set accordingly; see [ssh(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html#ENVIRONMENT). Unsetting the variable, e. g. in your `~/.bashrc`, or uninstalling the package should do the trick.

See also [Tell SSH to use a graphical prompt for key passphrase](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83986/tell-ssh-to-use-a-graphical-prompt-for-key-passphrase) for the reverse problem and some hints about the environment.

Comment: This most probably not be the case. SSH asks for passphrase always in the TTY, unless it does not have one (if you are in guake, I bet you have got one). The prompt is most probably from `gnome-keyring` (screenshot by the OP would confirm that), as explained in my other answer.

Comment: Indeed, the `gnome-askpass` window does not look like the usual: askpass only reads "Enter your OpenSSH passphrase" with a text field. I tried taking a screenshot, but it does not work: the window captures key events (same problem that causes the bug with fullscreen guake). I'll take a picture if need be.

Comment: @AdrienLuxey Try Gimp, it's able to take a screenshot of the active window after a timeout. But more importantly you should check the ps tree to see who/what calls the window.

Answer (score 3):

You have the private key added in the `gnome-keyring` or something else, which issues the GUI prompt for the passphrase. You can not get rid of that in this setup.

But there is possibility to use normal `ssh-agent` (by removing the `gnome-keyring` or starting `ssh-agent` after that) and `AddKeysToAgent yes` option in your `ssh_config`, which will result in the behavior you expect -- after the boot, the agent will not have any keys and they will be automatically added after the first use.

Similar cases are explained in related questions:

- [Save SSH key passphrase using keychain with --noask option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297955/save-ssh-key-passphrase-using-keychain-with-noask-option/297986#297986)
- [Sudo-like utility for ssh, or at least git in particular?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328975/sudo-like-utility-for-ssh-or-at-least-git-in-particular/328979#328979)